# Is it possible to have two GitLab accounts configured one Linux VM?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab, virtual-machine

I have myself and a partner that need to configure changes to one Git repo.

We have a Linux VM setup with only one generic service account, and would like to both push changes to the Repo.

From what I know you can have two ssh keys so what are the steps using the required `user.name` to push to the repo to see the user making the changes?

Comment: Ah, no. user.name and user.email are only used when you create revisions, not when you push. If you are using ssh, you could decide what certificate to use with `ssh-add` before you push to decide what user will be used to push into the remote (and they can be later removed with `ssh-add -d` so that you can choose the other certificates if you want.... under the same user).  This linux box is where you will host a common repo? Where will you be working from? Your own computers, separate from the linux server? Or you will also work on that same box?

Comment: Oh, I see, you will both work from that same linux VM on a project that has a repo in gitlab, is that the case? So, a few more questions: Do you use separate users on the linux box? If the answer is yes: then each one of you can set up separate certificates on that linux box. If the answer is "no", then you need to keep different certificates on the box so that when you want to push each one of you can add their own certificate so to be able to work against the gitlab repo with the right creds.

Comment: Yes, at the moment we have one user for the VM, so looks like we need different certificates. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @YusufMusaji I have edited your question to add some details: could you confirm my edits reflect adequately your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use:

- an HTTPS URL for the remote repository
- a git wrapper which will ask for your GitLab username and cache it in memory, once per session.
- a credential helper which will cache your GitLab account password, once per session.
  You can set it once and for all with:
  `git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=36000"`

I have written [`VonC/gitw`](https://github.com/VonC/gitw) to force a user to select their username at the first git command. Any subsequent git command will use that same `user.name`/`user.email` for any commit done.

Comment: Amazing and I will definitely have a look at your repo, appreciate it

Comment: @YusufMusaji Yes, with that option, no need for different certificates.